# python how to get the data of this script

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am using scrapy with python

this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS = {
        GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE: 55.4159330979,
        GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE: 25.1549968578
    };
</script>
```

I want to get the value of Longitude and Latitude.

I used this xpath to find the script:

```
.//script[contains(text(), 'window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS')]/text()
```

I got the whole text inside the script.

#### What I thought

1. Use aa josn parser library with python.
2. User a regular expression.

The second way is better since it is supported by `scrapy`

So, can you tell what what is the regular expression statment to extract those two attributes?

Best

#### Edit

when trying the first answer I got this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex to get to get the two floats:

```
re.compile(r'GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+),\s*GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+)')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputtext = '''\
... <script type="text/javascript">
...     window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS = {
...         GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE: 55.4159330979,
...         GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE: 25.1549968578
...     };
... </script>
... '''
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+),\s*GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+)')
>>> pattern.search(inputtext).groups()
('55.4159330979', '25.1549968578')
```

And used in the context of Scrapy selectors:

```
>>> import re
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> inputtext = """<script type="text/javascript">
...     window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS = {
...         GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE: 55.4159330979,
...         GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE: 25.1549968578
...     };
... </script>"""
>>> selector = Selector(text=inputtext, type="html")
>>> regexp = re.compile(r'GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+),\s*GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+)')
>>> selector.xpath('.//script[contains(text(), "window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS")]/text()').re(regexp)
[u'55.4159330979', u'25.1549968578']
```

Comment: I will try it now. please is there any way so I use just the xpath without the regular expression please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: I don't think so; regular expressions are an XPath extension and only (IIRC) to test, not to extract.

Comment: I tried your answer and I got an exception which is posted in the edited question. would you check it please

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: I cannot see where you made the mistake in your screenshot, post the *code*.

Comment: also are you sure that the input text is correct? because It seems that it is not completed, right?